# Commenter username copies author username

Tags: comments

There seems to be an error to the comment usernames, as it copies the username of the person who published the post. An example is here: http://www.friendshipscans.com/%E2%98%86-release-7/

Is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: Possibly but can you post the code that displays this? It's not possible to tell just from looking at the frontend. As an aside, there's super weird scrolling behaviour on that site, it gives slight motion sickness, can you fix that?

Comment: Have you considered contacting https://asiathemes.com/esol-details/ support? Or is this a problem that only happens with the child theme you created? Keep in mind that if your question needs somebody to spend cash on buying the parent theme then your chances of getting an answer on a public site are vanishingly small ( think winning the lottery ), and you'd be better hiring a developer or contacting the theme authors